# inserting a value in codeigniter shows no error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, post

I am trying to insert a row to the db using codeigniter. 
Model-**post.php**

```
class Post extends CI_Model{
    function get_posts($num=20, $start=0){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($num,$start);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_post($postid){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active' => 1, 'postID'=>$postid))->order_by('date_added','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');

    }

    function insert_post($data){
        $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
        return $this->db->return_id();
    }
```

Controller-**posts.php**

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('post');
    }
    function index(){
        $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('post_index', $data);
    }

    function post($postid){
        $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($postid);
        $this->load->view('post',$data);
    }

    function new_post(){
        if($_POST){
            $data =array(
                    'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                    'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                    'active'=>1
                );
            $this->post->insert_post($data);
            redirect(base_url());
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('new_post');
        }
    }
```

View-**new_post.php**

```
<form action="<?php base_url(); ?>posts/new_post" method="action">
    <p>Title: <input type="text" name="title"></p>
    <p>Description: <input type="textarea" name="post"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add post">
</form>
```

Index view-**post_index.php**

```
foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
<div id-="container">
    <div><h3><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>post/<?php echo $post['postID']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?> </a></h3>
        <?php echo $post['post']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

The index page shows all the posts from db. On clicking the title it takes to post.php view to show the respective data. This part is fine.
While trying to add a new post in new_post.php it is not reflecting in the db nor showing any error. 
Also I used redirect_url to redirect to the index page after inserting. So it shows the same available posts. On clicking the title it keeps on adding **posts/post** to the url repeatedly. 
Clicking the title once after redirecting the url shows

> http://localhost/Codeigniter/posts/posts/post/1

Again on clicking the title it adds

> http://localhost/Codeigniter/posts/posts/post/post/1

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think your `base_url` is set incorrectly. if you go to `application\config\config.php` what do you have set for `$config['base_url']` ??

Comment: there might be a typo in `post_index.php`, look at the line `<div id-="container">`

Answer (score 0):

in your model

```
 function insert_post($newpost){
        $this->db->insert('posts',$newpost);

        // check if the record was added 
        if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {
         // return new id
         return $this->db->insert_id();}

        else {return FALSE;}        
    }
```

**any user input must be validated**. if you are using Codeigniter then use its form validation and use its input library like:

```
$this->input->post('title')
```

an example for blog posts are in the tutorial https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

otherwise in your controller -- check if the new post id did not come back from the model -- if it did not come back then just go to an error method within the same controller so you don't lose the php error messages.

```
if ( ! $postid = $this->post->insert_post($newpost); ){

   // passing the insert array so it can be examined for errors
   $this->showInsertError($newpost) ;  } 

else { 
      // success now do something else ; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues across the entire application. These are what I found:

---

**Views**

Two problems in your `new_post` view.

1. You are not echoing out your `base_url` . You need to replace your form's action attribute.
2. the `method` attribute should either have `post` or `get`. In this case it should be `post`

Change it like this:

From this:

```
<form action="<?php base_url(); ?>posts/new_post" method="action">
```

To this:

```
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>posts/new_post" method="post">
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/new_post" method="post">
```

---

**Controller**

In your `posts` controller, your `new_post()` function should be like this:

```
function new_post() {
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'post' => $this->input->post('post'),
            'active' => 1
        );
        $id = $this->post->insert_post($data);// this is the id return by your model.. dont know what you wann do with it
        // maybe some conditionals checking if the $id is valid
        redirect(base_url());
    } else {
        $this->load->view('new_post');
    }
}
```

---

**Model**

function `insert_post()` should not have `$this->db->return_id();`, instead it should be `$this->db->insert_id();`

Comment: whoops -- where did return_id() come from? :-) (corrected my answer)